# VS2013: How to make #if DEBUG code run?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug a C# application, and I've defined some debug-only code within #if DEBUG/#endif blocks, and despite setting the build to Debug and double-checking the project properties and ensuring it's set to output to Debug and that the "Define DEBUG constant" checkbox is checked, my code isn't running. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#if DEBUG
    log.Add("Executing this section of code.");
#endif
```

and also

```
#if DEBUG
    SkipToThisOtherMethod();
    return;
#endif
```

It's blowing right past without running that code. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Are you sure you have compiled after setting the "Define DEBUG constant"? Because that *should* be the only thing you need. Also: do you have any `#undef DEBUG` anywhere?

Comment: I had no other such code like that. I suppose I assumed that clicking the "Start" button would compile the code; apparently not, because I just now used the "Rebuild solution" command and now it works. Please reply as an answer so I can give you credit for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ant, in case you want to have a build action executed when you click the Run/Start button, go into VS' options dialog and navigate to "Projections and Solutions" -> "Build and Run". There you should find several options regarding what should happen when you press the Run button. (I do not know the VS2013 options dialog in detail, but i hope they have not completely restructured it compared to older VS versions.)

Comment: I have the same problem, and the "Define DEBUG Constant" box *is* checked (it is on the Build section of the CSPROJ property page). The code worked under VS2010 but not under VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and seemed to resolve it by un-ticking the Define DEBUG Constant, saving the project, re-ticked it and saved the project again. Then Build and run and the #if DEBUG and #if !DEBUG sections went back to working normally.